# I add new CategoryViewController.swift, but I can't find it in custom class when I link new tableview to class

Tags: swift, xcode

I add new CategoryViewController.swift, but I can't find it in custom class when I link new table view to class.

[image]

Comment: Did you create the new file as a subclass of UITableViewController?

Comment: yeah, you are right, I do not change the UIViewController to UITableViewController

Answer (score -1):

- Try restarting Xcode
- And always start with a capital later when naming classes for example the name `toDoE...` should be `ToDoE...` I bet that might be the problem in your case